# Converting a list of nodes in preorder back into a binary tree

Tags: tree, language-agnostic, binary-tree, preorder

I have a list of nodes in preorder that I need to turn back into a tree.  I have a few guarantees about the resulting tree.

- It is a [full binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) meaning every node will have either 0 or 2 children.
- Whether or not the node is a leaf or a branch is contained in the preorder list.

I am sure a tree can be created as long as the above two constraints hold.

An example of a list of nodes in preorder might be:

```
Branch(1), Branch(2), Leaf(3), Branch(4), Leaf(5), Leaf(6), Branch(7)
```

The resulting tree:

```
       1
     /   \
   2       7
  / \
 3   4
    / \
   5   6
```

There is no other tree I can think of that could be build from the above preorder list.

I've tried a few different approaches (mostly with stacks and queues) but I've spent the last few hours on it and I haven't been able to get anything to work.

I'd prefer solutions in Rust but hints or solutions in C, C++, Python, Java, or even just pseudo code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the preorder traversal for restoring the binary tree if and only if the tree is a binary search tree. Simply, you insert the nodes in the same order than the traversal.

But if your tree is not a binary search tree, then you need to put the external nodes (null pointers) in your traversal. Some like that:

```
void preorder(Node * root)
{
  if (root == Node::NullPtr)
    {
      cout << "NULL ";
      return;
    }

  cout << root->key << " ";
  preorder(root->left);
  preorder(root->right);
}
```

Let us suppose that you have the preorder traversal in a `vector<string>` object, then in order to get the original tree, you can do:

```
Node * restore(const vector<string> & a, int & i)
{
  string key = a[i++];
  if (key == "NULL")
    return Node::NullPtr;

  Node * p = new Node;
  p->key = key;
  p->left = preorder(a, i);
  p->right = preorder(a, i);

  return p;
}
```

And the official interface would be:

```
Node * restore(const vector<string> & a)
{
  int i = 0;
  return restore(a, i)
}
```

Comment: It is not a bst so the first solution will not work. You also do not need to store null pointers in the preorder list because of the guarantee that every node will either have 0 or 2 children, and whether the node is a leaf or a branch is contained in each element of the preorder list.

Comment: @nickeb96 I would really appreciate knowing how. Consider, for instance, 2 nodes. The tree with root 2 and left child 1 has the same preorder traversal that the tree with root 1 and right child 2.  How do you do for distinguishing them? The more nodes you have the more different trees with same preorder traversal you have.

Comment: @nickeb96 you are right. I had not understood your problem statement. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

After giving it some time I have created a solution to my problem.

Basically you have a variable that holds the current node you are working on, starting with the root.  When you encounter a branch you add the branch to the current node's children and then you set the current node to that branch.  When you encounter a leaf you add the leaf to the current node's children.  You do this in a while loop until list is empty.  At the beginning of each loop iteration you check to see if the current node's children == 2, if so you make the node point to it's parent and you keep doing that until the current node variable points to a node that has < 2 children.

Here's my striped down Rust implementation:

```
struct Node { /* ... */ }
impl Node { /* ... */ }

enum NodeType {
    Branch(i32),
    Leaf(i32),
}

impl NodeType { /* ... */ }

fn list_to_tree(list: &[NodeType]) -> Node {
    let mut iter = list.iter();
    let root = Node::new(iter.next().unwrap().get_data());
    let mut node = &root;

    while let Some(next) = iter.next() {
        while node.child_count() == 2 {
            node = node.parent_ref();
        }

        match next {
            NodeType::Branch(data) => {
                node.add_child(Node::new(data));
                node = next;
            }
            NodeType::Leaf(data) => {
                node.add_child(Node::new(data));
            }
        }
    }

    root
}
```

It assumes that a non-empty list is given and that the list is a proper preorder list made from a tree with exactly 0 or 2 children per node.